# Is it possible to upgrade Windows 8 basic version to Windows 8 Pro using Windows upgrade offer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I have a Dell Inspiron Laptop which came pre installed with Windows 8 basic version. I have a Windows 8 Pro version which I acquired by using the windows upgrade offer. I would like to know if it is possible to upgrade my dell laptop with Windows 8 Pro which came pre installed with Windows 8 basic version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it is, go to the Metro Start Screen, search for "add features", say you already have a product key and enter it :)

Comment: Hi Taylor, thanks for you reply. I will certainly try this and let you know.

Comment: Please dont forget to mark as answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Done. I checked the same and was able to update to pro version. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The product key will be rejected because the key is for an upgrade fron an earlier version of Windows like XP or 7. I tried the same thing.

Edit: I just saw the previous answer where it worked. In my case, I installed Windows 8 on a new SSD drive in my new Laptop using the upgrade DVD. It did not ask for a key and announced itself as straight Windows 8. Trying to put in the supplied Pro upgrade key was rejected.

Comment: This really isn't an answer.   Although I don't disagree the "accepted" answer shouldn't work since `Windows 8` is only elibile to be upgrade to the `Windows 8` via the `Windows 8 Pro Pack`

Comment: In fact it worked for me. I upgraded to pro version using the key that I obtained by using the upgrade offer and later I upgraded to Windows 8 Pro with media center.